# Signal generator specifitc noise modulation

Tags: python, numpy, signals, noise

I am simulating a signal (see below) and I later add noise to it.
But I don't want add noise to every single sample point. So is there a way to set a defined amount of my noise array to zero (zeros has to be positioned randomly). nse_kappa and noise_mu are parameters defined for the noise distribution

```
   x  = np.zeros((n_epochs, times.size))
    for i in range(0,n_epochs):
        print("Signal simulation of Epoch %s complete") %(i+1)
        for j in range(0, freqs0.size):
            x[i] = x[i] + (np.sqrt(Rxx0[j]) * np.sin(1 * np.pi * freqs0[j] * times))
        x[i] = x[i] + np.random.normal(loc=noise_mu, scale= nse_kappa, size=times.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you add the noise, check if it should be added.

```
import random
for x in range(10):
    if random.uniform(0,1) > 0.5:
        print "Add noise"
    else:
        print "Do nothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for generating non-repetitive  random integers as index and use them for setting your array values to zero.

```
import random

# your code

N = 100 # number of indices set to zero
ind = random.sample(range(len(x)),N)
x[ind] = 0.
```